# Tying images in assets folder to elements in a list

Tags: angular

Using Angular 11, I have a list of games with their corresponding price, rating, etc. but I want to tie images from the assets folder to the games and I'm unsure how to do so.

So far I have the table header and space(td tag) within a ngFor(tr tag) prepared for where I want the image to display but I can't figure out how tie the image to the list element.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let game of games; let i = index"
    [class.active]="i == currentIndex"
    (click)="setActiveGame(game, i)">
  <td>{{game.gameId}}</td>
  <td>{{game.name}}</td>
  <td><img src="assets/'{{game.image}}'"></td>
  <td>{{game.price}}</td>
  <td>{{game.releaseDate}}</td>
```

Comment: You really need to include some actual code instead of describing what your code looks like.

Comment: So what path does an `image` string actually have, and what does it need to end up being?

Answer (score 1):

I think adding the path like this:

```
    <td><img [src]="'./path/to/assets/' + game.imageUrl"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add relative path of your image to the games array

```
    games = [
    {
    name: 'Game 1',
    price: 9.99,
    rating: 4.5,
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/game1.jpg'
    },
    .......
    ]
    <tr *ngFor="let game of games">
    <td><img [src]="game.imageUrl"></td>
    <td>{{ game.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ game.price }}</td>
    <td>{{ game.rating }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I somewhat understand but my data is coming from back end rather than being hard coded

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the most efficient way but I ended up creating a field in the database that holds the exact name of the image(along with its extension) and binded it on the front-end along with the rest of its data